# Vectorising a Matlab code to pick specific indices of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `Nx(N-1)`, e.g.

```
N=5;
A=[1  2  3  4; 
   5  6  7  8;
   9  10 11 12;
   13 14 15 16;
   17 18 19 20];
```

I want to rearrange the elements of `A` in a certain way. Specifically I want to create a matrix `B` of dimension `(N-1)xN` such that:

for `i=1,...,N`,

`B(:,i)` collects

1) the first `i-1` elements of the `i-1`th column of `A` and

2) the last `N-i` elements of the `i`th column of `A`.

Notice that for `i=1` the `i-1`th column of `A` does not exist and therefore 1) is skipped; similarly,  for `i=N` the`i`th column of `A` does not exist and therefore 2) is skipped.

---

In the example above

```
B=[5  1  2  3  4
   9  10 6  7  8
   13 14 15 11 12
   17 18 19 20 16];
```

---

This code does what I want. I am asking your help to vectorise it in an efficient way.

```
B=zeros(N-1,N);
for i=1:N
    if i>1 && i<N
    step1=A(1:i-1,i-1);
    step2=A(i+1:N,i);
    B(:,i)=[step1;step2];
    elseif i==1
    B(:,i)=A(i+1:N,i);     
    elseif i==N
    B(:,i)=A(1:i-1,i-1);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the lower and upper triangular matrices of `A`. Then reassemble them with a "diagonal shift":

```
u = triu(A);
l = tril(A,-1);
B = padarray(u(1:end-1,:),[0 1],'pre') + padarray(l(2:end,:),[0 1],'post');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another valid approach using [logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) combined with [`tril`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html) and [`triu`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html):

```
B = zeros(size(A'));
B(tril(true(size(B)))) = A(tril(true(size(A)), -1));
B(triu(true(size(B)), 1)) = A(triu(true(size(A))));
```

Result:

```
>> B

B =

     5     1     2     3     4
     9    10     6     7     8
    13    14    15    11    12
    17    18    19    20    16
```